# How can I do a git add --patch during an interactive rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-add

I want to go back and remove several portions of a commit that is two commits back.  I hoped I could do `git rebase -i HEAD^^`, `edit` the commit, and then use `git add --patch <file>` on the file.  However, during the rebase, `git reset HEAD <file>` doesn't appear to work because when I try `git add --patch <file>`, it says there are no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During rebase `HEAD` points to the latest commit that has been added onto the base. So `git reset head` between two rebase operation does nothing.

You need to reset to 1 commit before with `git reset HEAD^` and then (interactively) add the desired changes.

```
$ git rebase -i ... # change a commit to "edit"
$ git reset HEAD^
$ git add --patch
$ git commit
```

Possibly discard all remaining changes that were not commited:

```
$ git checkout .
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that, during an interactive rebase `HEAD` does not point to the previous commit, so `git reset HEAD` doesn't do anything.

Instead, find the hash of the previous commit using `git log` and then just run `git reset <hash> <file>`, followed by `git add --patch <file>`.

You can then run `git checkout -- <file>` to discard the rest of the changes.

Comment: surprised that this question/answer didn't get more votes?

Comment: HEAD never points to the previous commit but always to the latest one. Using the revision hash works but is not necessary.